# Add options to wordpress gallery function

Tags: wordpress, customization, gallery

Is it possible to add custom options (checkboxes and selectfields) to the default gallery settings in wordpress and then query them as parameters in the code?

Examples or links to corresponding tutorials would be great :)

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. You should consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rewriting your question to include some coding you've tried to show that you have put in a little effort before you came here.

Answer (score 0):

See if advancedcustomfields helps you. This allows you to create additional option fields. But then you would have to deal with the plugin yourself.

But if you do a lot with WordPress and with WordPress programming you can generally recommend advancedcustomfields anyway.

Comment: I know ACF but can you give galleries ACF-Fields? I want to use the native gallery-feature of the WYSIWYG-editor of wordpress and not make my own gallery with acf (that wouldn't be the problem).

If I can use ACF to add fields to the regular gallery-options, then could you explain how this works?

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/   I guess everything you need is here :-)  Maybe I understand you wrong, then sorry